# Drupal 7 / Wysiwyg module + full ckeditor : how to add downloaded plugins

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

In drupal 7, I've installed the wysiwyg module. I downloaded the full ckeditor into sites/all/libraries.

I selected ckeditor to use as my wysiwyg editor in the drupal admin. Next, I can create a wyswiyg profile and toggle plugins on and off, amongst others.

I even created a module to add some custom things using HOOK_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter. So I know all that.

But when I want to add ckeditor addons downloaded from the web, I have mixed results. Some just work if I add them to the sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins folder and add a line to HOOK_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter to register the plugin.

But some don't. And I never see the plugins reflected in my wysiwyg profile in the admin.

What is the proper way to add plugins to the full ckeditor when using the wysiwyg module ?

Comment: Not to steer you off topic, but is there a reason for using wysiwyg module instead of the ckeditor module? Unless you want more than one editor, I find ckeditor module more stable and easier to extend. For example, putting the plugin in the ckeditor plugins directory creates a checkbox in the text profile to turn it on.  *Note: we are having some trouble getting drag and drop working*

Comment: It's a live site. They actually came from Wysiwyg+TinyMCE :-) I'm not going to swap now.